# Json data from server not populating backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am new to Backbone.js and Require.js I am trying to get data from the server and store it in my backbone model. The problem is the data is not populating the model.

```
require.config({
paths:{
    jquery:"libs/jquery-1.7.1.min",
    underscore:"libs/underscore-min",
    backbone:"libs/backbone-min",
    models:"models",
    views:"views",
    collections:"collections"
},
shim:{
    "backbone":{
        "deps":["underscore","jquery"],
        "exports":"Backbone"
         },
        "underscore":{
             "exports":"_"
        }
     }
   });


 require (['routes'],function() {
      new Router ();
 });
```

The Model

```
define (['jquery','underscore','backbone'],function($,_,Backbone){
Video = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    defaults:{
        video_id:'',
        video_name:'',
    },
    urlRoot:"/video",
});
});//end define
```

The Router

```
define(['backbone','models/Video'],function(Backbone){
 Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "/":"index",
    },
    initialize:function (){
        this.index ();
    },
    index:function ()
    {
        video = new Video ({id:"1Uw6ZkbsAH8"});
        video.fetch();
        console.log (video.toJSON());
    }
 }); 
});//end define
```

I check the network response and I am getting "{video_id:1,video_name:test_backbone}" as a response but when I console.log (video.toJSON()) i get - Object {id: "1Uw6ZkbsAH8", video_id: "", video_name: ""}. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code logging is done right after the `fetch` is called. `fetch` makes an asycnhronous request to server for data. Your logging call is executed right away even before the network request is completed. this is one of the gotchas of event-based programming.

try calling `console.log` in the `success` callback.

```
video.fetch ( { 
    success: console.log(video.toJSON()); 
    } 
);
```